# QSqlDatabase: driver not loaded, from within another dll

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

There are tons of queries on internet regarding the failure of load of drivers but my situation looks unique. Please help.

I have created a dll of my code and it uses QSqlDatabase. So the dependency is like mylib.dll->qt5sql.dll->qsqlpsql.dll
When I run a test app using mylib.dll, it is not able to load the driver. It lists down the available drivers as shown below:
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

However, when I try to use my code as a static library, it is working absolutely fine. So the dependency on libpq.dll, values of PATH etc are all ok. Has anyone else faced such issue?

Comment: Do you have all the three dlls within the same folder as the text app executable?

Comment: I have tried multiple combinations in this regard. 1. Copied the exe and all the dlls (including qt5core and qt5sql) in the same folder. 2. exe and plugins/sqldrivers/driverdlls 3. exe and sqldrivers/driverdlls 4. The default installation of qt.  I have also used QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("./plugins"); but it works only outside my code's  dll. It shows no effect whatsoever. Tried even setLibraryPath() for that matter.

Comment: Here's one other thing you could try: 1. Put the driver into `sqldrivers` folder near your executable 2. Add `sqldrivers` folder to the library paths via `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath`. 3. Try to load the driver manually before using it in your code: `QPluginLoader loader("sqldrivers/qsqlpsql.dll"); loader.load();`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. As you see in my anser, my issue was something else. However, your tips would be helpful for someone else sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was not the issue of QT but a problem in my DLL due to the use of static variables in my source code. As we know, two different instances of  a static variable gets created at runtime (each for the exe and the DLL) if it is not the part of DLL code. I had a static library which contained these static variables. This static library was linked to create a DLL. So basically the driver name was not getting passed to the DLL thereby resulting in "Driver not loaded" error. I have fixed the issue by eliminating the static library creation. Now the source code is being built together to create the DLL.

Comment: How to "Eliminate the static library creation" please ?

Comment: Your question is very short and unclear. Check the compiler flags to avoid static lib creation. CMake and other tools provide their own ways. Enough info is available.